What's the shortest way to link to an answer on Retrocomputing?
Not asking for 3rd party URL shorteners. Just what works here.
For example, I can shorten
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/455592/131624
down to just
swe.stackexchange.com/a/455592
but
https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11502/771
I only know how to get down to
retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11502
I tried
rc.stackexchange.com/a/11502
and
retro.stackexchange.com/a/11502
but they don't work. Ideas? Are the shorter subdomains listed somewhere?

We don't have a shorter domain name than that. Iirc, Stack Exchange isn't in the habit of creating new domain aliases, because it's a pain to manage even the existing ones. (I'll write up an answer if I find the reference.)

Why does it matter to anyone?  The displayed text and the link are not the same thing.

@dave it may shock and amaze you but even in this day an age people use paper.

As do I, particularly when programming.  But I've rarely found a link on paper to be useful.

You already have the shortest form: //retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11502.
The API query shows that Retrocomputing has no domain-name aliases.
